# Backbone change event on two separate value, mutex'd

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Backbone model with two properties I am listening for a change on.

```
this.model.on("change:foo", this.doFoo, this);
this.model.on("change:bar", this.doBar, this);
```

However, there are moments when both foo and bar change at the same instant.  Is it possible to cancel the event if foo is changed, so that if both foo and bar change, I only execute doFoo?

I know I can do this using a general change event and examine the changes, but I'm hoping for something a little more baked in.

```
this.model.on("change", this.doFooOrBar, this);
```

The purpose is to avoid convoluted code, so if it involves a bunch of hacky things I'd rather just do a generic change event and react accordingly.  These are the only two properties I'm monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an anonymous function is an acceptable solution?

```
this.model.on("change", function () {

    if (this.model.hasChanged('foo')) {
        this.doFoo();
    }
    if (this.model.hasChanged('bar') && !this.model.hasChanged('foo')) {
        this.doBar();
    }

});
```